# How to print partial URL after #?

Tags: slug

In WordPress, is it possible to retrieve the part of the URL after a `#`?

I'm trying `echo the_slug();` but it's showing front slug. But I want after #tag

For example: I'm searching and land on this page. And print last anchor text.

http://www.mywebsite.com/test/#test1 >> Output: test1

http://www.mywebsite.com/test/#test-test2 >> Output: test-test2

Comment: `the_slug()` is no native WordPress function... where does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the "slug" is what it is by definition. There is no such thing as a "front slug".

As you do not elaborate/know on how the anchors/hashes are generated on the server side, all I can give you is a JS solution (proof of concept):

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    alert(window.location.hash.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: Hi Pille, no It's not server side. Anchors/hashes give from backend only for admin. And I'm display (http://www.mywebsite.com/test/#test1) test1 in this page.

Comment: The backend does not "give" anchors just like that. I have a distinct feeling you have no idea what "server side" means. Sorry to say. Try to use the above. Best solution I can give you.

Comment: Sorry Pille, I'm not well programming. But your answer is correct. Now showing fine. Thanks.

Comment: You have any idea? How put this value in PHP variable.

Comment: PHP == server side --> You need to figure out where it comes from / is generated.